# Python get full response from a get request

Tags: python, python-requests, xss

I'm needing to write a script to confirm a part of website is vulnerable to reflected XSS but the request response doesn't contain complete HTML so I can't check it for the payload. For example in Burb the response contains the whole page HTML where I can see the 'alert('xss')' but in Python it does not. I've tried response.text/content etc. but they're all the same. Is there a seperate module for this stuff or am I just doing something wrong with the request?

```
for p in payloads:
response = requests.get(url+p)
if p in response.content:
    print(f'Vulnerable: payload - {p}')
```

Burp response does contain the following

```
<pre>Hello <script>alert("XSS")</script></pre>
```

I need to have the same thing in the Python response

Comment: You might want to use an f-string to form the url and p instead of +

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that that part of the script only will load after a few seconds after GET. When using the request module, it will return the first thing it sees (i.e. the unloaded script).

To go around this you may want to use a web driver module like selenium that allows waiting before getting the HTML